# Shared printer hosted by Windows 7 to XP peers

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Network Printer drivers in Windows 7/Server 2008 R2?](https://superuser.com/questions/59067/add-network-printer-drivers-in-windows-7-server-2008-r2)

A Canon Pixma ip4600 installed all by itself when connected to a Windows 7-64 bit machine.  I then updated it with the add-on Canon provide to give additional functionality.

I then wish to share it with a box which is running Windows XP 32-bit.  The XP box can see the printer but can't find a driver from the 7 machine, which is fine.  I ask the 7 machine to get the x86 drivers, but it can't.

I install the 32-bit XP drivers on the XP machine, but unlike previous Canon drivers (which unzip to give an .inf file), they assume a local printer and partially give up.  I find the .inf file in the `Program files\CanonBJ\...` directory.

Neither the XP machine, nor the 7 machine when the CanonBJ directory is shared to it, is happy with the .inf file.

I attempt to install the 32-bit drivers on the 64-bit 7 machine, which, understandably, fail.

Where do we go from here?

(I apologise for posting in the first-person, I'm not sure why this was)

Comment: Can you move the computer (or the printer) and get the 32 bit drivers to install if you connect it locally?  Then once the drivers are on board you may be able to share to it from the 32 bit box.

Comment: That probably would work, though as a comment I can't accept as an answer.  In reality I connected it locally just for expediency after installing 7 on the other machine, but your solution should've worked equally as well.  A little annoying regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See and adapt my answer in this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/59067/add-network-printer-drivers-in-windows-7-server-2008-r2) to your case.

In a nutshell, what you have to do is :

1. Install the printer on the XP 
   machine, which you can most easily
   do    if you connect the printer
   directly    to it
2. Move the printer back to the Win7
   machine
3. Convert this XP printer into a
   network printer, as explained in the
   above thread.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  The Solution proposed by Michael Pryor on OCtober 30 does not work.  I have XP machines with drivers which DO work in communicating with two Vista 64 boxes.  However, after on the Vista boxes was upgraded to Windows 7 (64), the drivers on XP boxes do not work and the printer on the Windows 7 box is no longer functional for them.  The Flag said, the xp machines can see the windows 7 printer, but not print to it.  I have read in other forums that Windows 7 machines are able to connect printers physically attached to XP machines.