# How does one extract the Canon ip4600 drivers in inf form?

Tags: windows, drivers, printer

I have a x64 machine which needs "additional drivers" for x86 clients. The problem I have is I cannot get the proper .inf files so I can use them. Canon only provides an .exe file, which when extracted has other .exe files and some dll files.

I believe Canon changed their drivers, because I did have them extracted at one point, but sadly did not save them :(.

The drivers are available [here](http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&tabact=DownloadDetailTabAct&fcategoryid=357&modelid=17105). Hopefully I am clear in what I am trying to do. Canon provides the .exe file. The .exe file when extracted does not produce any .inf driver files.

Thanks!

Comment: I should note this is for Windows 7 x64, and I want Windows 7 x86 drivers (although I believe any x86 drivers would work).

I should also note, the XP version of this driver (which claims it is the same as the Vista version) does extract just fine.

Comment: the procedure in [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/59067/add-network-printer-drivers-in-windows-7-server-2008-r2) may help.

Answer (score 1):

You could try extracting the contents of the exe file using [Universal extractor](http://legroom.net/software/uniextract). It works quite well with most exe files and it's free so it could be worth a try.

Comment: 1 UP: winrar will also do this

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the drivers from the Windows XP 64 installer. For my IP1600, I had to download the windows XP 64 bit driver, extract it, and point to the extracted folder. I used Universal Extractor to extract the files. The file was called "ip1600.inf" in my case, so I would guess "ip4600.inf" for yours? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - Windows 7 x64 client, Vista x86 32-bit server.
If I connected the iP4600 directly to the client, then driver installed OK.
If I connected the iP4600 to the Vista 32-bit server, then tried to add the printer as a remote printer from my 64-bit client machine, no driver could be found for the client.

Managed to solve the problem by explicitly downloading the Vista x64 driver from [here](http://www.usa.canon.com/consumer/controller?act=ModelInfoAct&tabact=DownloadDetailTabAct&fcategoryid=357&modelid=17105) on my Windows 7 client PC, then adding the remote printer again.