# My laptop won't recognize a shared printer on the network

Tags: windows-7, printer

I have a computer network. The desktop (Windows Vista) is hardwired to the router and the printer. I added a HP laptop (windows 7) to the network. I cannot get the laptop to print anything. I downloaded recent Windows 7 drivers from Canon printers to the laptop but it still will not recognize the printer, or the printer will not recognize the laptop. Can you help with this problem? Sounds like a driver problem maybe I need to download canon vista printer driver to the laptop. Any Ideas would be helpful.

Comment: This needs a much more descriptive title.

Comment: @pcapademic: A year and months later, while pruning short titles. Your request is now being handled... ^^

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is because one machine is 32bits while the other is 64bits, then see my [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/59067/add-network-printer-drivers-in-windows-7-server-2008-r2/59462#59462) in another thread.

You'll need to ignore the bits that are specific to the problem being discussed and adapt it to your situation, but this should be easy.