# Installing HomeGroup Printer

Tags: windows-7, printer, homegroup

I have two Windows 7 computers on a HomeGroup. I am on "Computer A" and need to access a printer connected to "Computer B". On Computer A, the HomeGroup panel tells me that it found a new shared printer on my home network and provides a button to "Install printer". However, when I click on it, nothing happens... Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding the printer manually using the drivers that came on the CD or off the OEM's website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Microsoft article might help: [Install a printer on a home network](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Install-a-printer-on-a-home-network).
Verify that you didn't miss out on a step.

> To manually connect to a homegroup
>   printer
>
> 1. On the computer the printer is physically connected to, click the
>      Start button and then click Control
>      Panel. In the search box, type
>      homegroup, and then click HomeGroup.
> 2. Make sure the Printers check box is selected. (If not, select it, and
>      then click Save changes.)
> 3. Go to the computer you want to print from.
> 4. Open HomeGroup by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start
>      button, clicking Control Panel, typing
>      homegroup in the search box, and then
>      clicking HomeGroup.
> 5. Click Install printer.
> 6. If you don't already have a driver installed for the printer, click
>      Install driver in the dialog box that
>      appears.

Comment: This is exactly what I have tried. The "Install printer" button itself will not click (it is active, but it won't click).

Comment: Is there a mismatch between the machines as regarding 32/64-bits ?

Comment: Computer A is Windows 7 Professional 32 bit, and Computer B is Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit.

Comment: Try to connect A directly to the printer. Then convert the created local printer to a network printer as described here : http://superuser.com/questions/59067/add-network-printer-drivers-in-windows-7-server-2008-r2/59462#59462