# How do I install a Windows 7 Homegroup printer?

Tags: windows-7, printer, homegroup

I have a local printer on Desktop A and I want to use it on LapTop B.  I have made a homegroup and can copy files between the two computers.  On Desktop A I have the 'Printers' checked, in order to share the printer.  The printer works great on Desktop A.  I wish to print to it from Laptop B

Elsewhere on the internet and on [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/93341/installing-homegroup-printer) I see instructions to click Homegroups in the Control Panel, and then click "install printer".  However, in the homegroups dialog (titled "Change Homegroup Setting", I don't see an "install printer" button anywhere.  how do I make is show up?

Answer (score 1):

Partick,

check this [forum](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/2479-cant-join-homegroup-13.html).

From this it looks like other users are having the same issue. Perhaps turning off a third party firewall will make a difference.

Comment: Actually, I can join the homegroup with no problem.  It's just that the "install printer" button is not there for me.