# Cannot scan using TWAIN driver from Ricoh Aficio Printer

Tags: microsoft-word, windows-server-2008, scanner, scanning

2 days before I formatted my Windows 2008 Server SP2 system and reinstalled the same OS. There is a network printer (Ricoh Aficio MP C2030) in my office, which can be used both as a printer and a scanner. I successfully installed the driver to print on my system.

Also I installed the scanner driver (TWAIN driver), which I got from their official website. But I cannot scan documents from the printer. Earlier I used to scan documents through MS Word using the printer. The steps were:

- Open MS Word
- Press ALT + IPS
- A window of Scanner opens in Word.

But now when I press ALT + IPS, MS Word crashes. How can I scan using Ricoh Aficio MP C2030?

---

UPDATE:

I made the settings in the TWAIN Network Connection Tool.

[image]

But still I cannot use the scanner. Other computers in the network can use the scanner.

---

UPDATE:

I found this link http://support.ricoh.com/bb_v1oi/pub_e/oi_view/0001035/0001035358/view/scanner/unv/0110.htm, which says I have to install DesktopBinder Lite. So I downloaded a 64 bit version of it and tried to install. But I got an error-

[image]

What to do now?

---

UPDATE:

This is what i get when I pres ALT+IPS in Word:
[image]

And when I click Ok:
[image]

Comment: check to see if the plug in has been disabled by Word.

Comment: @BenPlont Can you tell the steps for it ?

Comment: In word go to file > options ad-ins > manage ad-is.

Comment: First, fully update Windows via Windows Update for device-oriented items in the  Optional section. Give us more info regarding the crashes if they continue. Does the printer work for printing?

Comment: @harrymc Windows updates are applied. The printer works for printing. What I came to know is I have to install DeskTopBinder, but am getting the error (stated above) when installing the 64 bit version.

Comment: Some info about the Office crash would still be useful. Are you sure you had DeskTopBinder in your previous installation?

Comment: More questions: (1) Are you able to scan documents not through Word? If not - (2) Is it feasible as a test to scan while connecting the printer directly to the computer via cable?

Comment: @harrymc I don't know how to scan not through word. Actually I was searching for that also. Since it is a network printer I cannot connect directly to my computer. And whatever methods I tried in word, they all gave the error 'Unable to connect to scanner or camera' (Shown in one image above). So I think the scanner driver is not properly installed.

Comment: Do not use the outdated Ricoh tools and uninstall their printer. Follow this [Microsoft guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/install-printer#install-printer=windows-7), or just use Windows Explorer, Network section, to click or right-click on the printer to install. Ensure the Windows Image Acquisition service is started. Then try IPS again. If no go, try to acquire not thru Office, for example using [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/index.html) menu *File -> Acquire*.

Comment: I think it is not outdated Ricoh tools. I downloaded it from their website. Anyway I will follow the microsoft guide.

Comment: @harrymc Followed the Microsoft guide and installed the printer again. The driver of my printer is Ricoh Aficio MP C2030 RPCS.

Comment: I presume IPS still doesn't work. You might have the wrong driver, but can fix this by connecting it via cable, reinstalling the printer as local and try acquire in Paint.NET and then IPS. Once it works this way, you can convert the printer to network (see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/59462/8672)).

Comment: @harrymc What is IPS?

Comment: @harrymc And sadly Paint.NET is not supported in my system. It requires Windows 7 SP1 or higher.

Comment: You can also use [Windows Fax and Scan](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/scan-a-document-or-photo-with-windows-fax-and-scan) if you have it.

Comment: @harrymc Windows Fax and Scan is not there in my system.

Comment: Can you add the Fax Server role? See [this answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-desktop/where-did-windows-fax-and-scan-go-in-windows-2008/bce978a3-e561-4d40-8ae8-0457ce736d04).

Answer (score 1):

DeskTopBinder has been [discontinued](http://support.ricoh.com/html_gen/util/DTB/DTB_R.html) since December 31, 2013.
You need another solution.

See the article [Scanning in Word 2013](http://www.borncity.com/blog/2013/02/04/scanning-in-word-2013/) for detailed instructions on how
to add a button in the Word toolbar for scanning.

The author also supplies
a [download](http://www.borncity.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Scan1.zip) file containing a template .docm file and a macro code file (.bas) with a a ready to use solution. You may use the sample and copy the macro code to your Normal.dot file.

For more information, see the article [Installing macros](http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm).

Another very detailed article describing a similar solution can be found in :

- [Scanning in Word 2013/2016 – Part I](http://borncity.com/win/2016/03/03/sscanning-in-word-20132016-part-i/)
- [Scanning in Word 2013/2016 – Part II](http://borncity.com/win/2016/03/04/scanning-in-word-20132016-part-ii/)

Comment: Can you explain it a little more? Am not experienced with these.

Comment: I tried this: http://blog.duklabs.com/?p=200 But the second method told me 'Unable to connect to Scanner or Camera'

Comment: The best way to gain experience is to go ahead. I mentioned two articles, because between them they should explain the procedure. The article you have found is a very simple method along the same route - I know about it but do not recommend it. Just take the one of my two articles that you like better and go slowly, googling for info as necessary (you will find heaps).

Comment: Lets comment the rest here. I added the Fax Server role. From the last link you provided, I tried method 1 in it and was unable to find scanner.

Comment: Are your drivers the latest ones from [this page](http://support.ricoh.com/bb/html/dr_ut_e/ra/model/mpc20l/mpc20len.htm#Microsoft%20Windows%20Server%202008%20%28x64%29)? You might try some of the downloads from 2016 rather than from 2013. Do you have an image backup of the computer from before you formatted it? One should always keep such an image and a backup of all drivers before reformatting.

Comment: Yes, they are latest and downloaded it earlier from the link you provided. I am using RPCS driver for printing and also installed TWAIN driver.

Comment: RPCS is from 2008 (!), TWAIN from 2013. Do you remember your setup from before you formatted? Have you tried to connect via cable?

Comment: Am not remembering the setup before formatting, because at that time I was not here. The printer is connected via cable.

Comment: Only two possibilities : PC driver or printer firmware. For the PC, try the latest PCL driver with PrinterSwitcher. If this doesn't help, then firmware updates are complicated, since only Ricoh technicians with a valid ID can log into [that site](http://ssoappprod.ricoh-usa.com:8080/opensso/UI/Login). You will then need help from their Support.