# Use on windows 7 x32 a shared printer installed on windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printing, printer

I have a Samsung ml-1670 printer. I have installed it on Windows 7 x64. The printer is shared.

I want to use this on a Windows 7 x32 pc, but I have problems installing drivers. I can see the printer on the network, but when I try to install, it says that can't find drivers. I point manually on a folder where there are drivers for windows 7 x32, but it continues to say that it can't find drivers.

What can I do? Is it possible to use on windows 7 x32, a printer that is installed on windows 7 x64?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You’re going to have to provide more details and ask more specific questions.

Comment: @Appleoddity I've started the wizard to install a network printer , I've found  the shared printer on network  , when the wizard is searching for drivers it says that it cannot find on network computer where the printer is installed , so I've point to a folder on x32 pc where there are x32 drivers , but again it says that cannot find drivers.

Comment: That is what your post above already says. What we really need are specifics, some screenshots, etc. I’m asking because this is fairly straight forward. We need to see what steps you’re taking and where you’re going wrong. We need to see actual driver files you’re trying, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for some reason this network printer is not exposing a 32-bit driver,
which is more than puzzling, even worrisome.
It might possibly mean a defective printer firmware.

I can detail below the procedures that usually solve such problems.
If none of them works, then something is wrong with the printer itself.

The printer on the Windows 7 x64 must be shared, let's say it's named "PrinterName".

You may find your printer software on this [Support page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-ml-1670-laser-printer-series/17156953).
Download the driver for Windows 7 32-bit and install it locally.
You should then be able to see the printer in network neighborhood and use it.

If that doesn't work, then you could first connect the printer to the Windows 7 32-bit
computer and install it as a local printer, then move it back to its computer and
convert the local printer to network printer as detailed in
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/59462/8672).

Still another method is to use the Add New Printer wizard,
start a Local Printer, select New Port of type Local Port,
and type `\\MACHINENAME\PrinterName`.
If you need to select a driver, select yours from the list.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's x86 not x32

When that is said, i just googled samsung ml 1670 driver, and what do you know. A download page for the driver is the topmost result.

Visit the following link from the computer running 32-bit (x86) Windows:

https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-ml-1670-laser-printer-series/17156953

Input the correct OS, click download.

Running a virus scan on downloaded files **before** you open them is a good idea on Windows.

Run installer when download is finished.

As a rule of thumb, you should only download executables from sites you trust.

My educated guess would be that https://support.hp.com is a safe source for downloads since Hewlett Packard is a well known brand, and the domain certificates are okay.